# angular-oauth2-oidc wont resolve in angular 9

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement authentication in my angular app. I went to install oauth2-oidc using  `npm i angular-oauth2-oidc`

Here is my app module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OAuthModule } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc/angular-oauth-oidc.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I go to serve using `ng s` I get the following error

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular-oauth2-oidc/angular-oauth-oidc.module' in '...\source\repos\ezgig-web\src\app'
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
> Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
> Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
> Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'

Comment: Just change the import to `import { OAuthModule } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc'`

Comment: thats done it! cheers